# JQuery POST login to external website without confirm prompt

Tags: jquery

I've created this function to send a login request to an external website which works well but each time it pops up with a message saying "Accept login details from the website at 'http://..."

Is there a way to stop this message popping up?

```
function login() {
    var TARGET_URI = "https:\/\/url.com";
    var SESSIONKEY = "<?php echo $login["response"]->SessionKey; ?>";
    var USERNAME = "<?php echo $account["username"]; ?>";

    var wnd = window.open( TARGET_URI );
    if (wnd === null) {
        return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('message', function(msg) {
        wnd.postMessage(
            {"msg": "user_session_login", "username": USERNAME, "sessionkey": SESSIONKEY },
            TARGET_URI
        );
        $("#waiting").hide();
        $("#complete").show();
        window.close();
    }, TARGET_URI);
}
```

Comment: post more details, can you post a fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature of the web browser that informs the user that a website is trying to communicate with another website.

Known as the Same Origin Policy (SOP), if you are in control of the pages you can implement Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

A serverside Proxy or a pre-aut of your TARGET_URI.

Something in the line of:

```
var TARGET_URI = http://User:Pass@ip
```